# Как поменять значения осей местами в обьекте QValueAxis

Tags: qt, pyqt5, qt5, pyside2

Данным кодом я устанавливаю от -3 до 3, а надо от 3 до -3:

```
QValueAxis.setRange(-3,3)
```

Просто поменяв значения в скобках не получается.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Надо использовать метод [QAbstractAxis.setReverse(true)](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractaxis.html#reverse-prop).

Есть ограничения:

Обратная ось поддерживается сериями линий, сплайнов и рассеяния, а также сериями площадей с декартовой системой координат